# Swift Error - 'Cannot invoke value of type 'SwiftStockChart.LabelForValueGetter' (aka'(Int) -> String') with argument list '(Value:Int)'

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, int

I am getting an error when I am trying to set the chart points from the Yahoo Finance API using Swift.

The error says

> Cannot invoke value of type 'SwiftStockChart.LabelForValueGetter'
>   (aka'(Int) -> String') with argument list '(Value:Int)'

And this is on line.

```
let text = labelForIndex(index: i)
```

The full code is:

```
func setChartPoints(points: [ChartPoint]) {

if points.isEmpty { return }

dataPoints = points

computeBounds()


if maxValue!.isNaN { maxValue = 1.0 }

for i in 0 ..< verticalGridStep! {

    let yVal = axisHeight! + margin! - CGFloat((i + 1)) * axisHeight! / CGFloat(verticalGridStep!)
    let p = CGPoint(x: (valueLabelPosition! == .right ? axisWidth! : 0), y: yVal)

    let text = labelForValue(value: minValue! + (maxValue! - minValue!) / CGFloat(verticalGridStep!) * CGFloat((i + 1)))

    let rect = CGRect(x: margin!,  y: p.y + 2, width: self.frame.size.width - margin! * 2 - 4.0, height: 14.0)
    let width = text.boundingRect(with: rect.size,
                                  options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                  attributes:[NSFontAttributeName : valueLabelFont!],
                                  context: nil).size.width

    let xPadding = 6
    let xOffset = width + CGFloat(xPadding)

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: p.x - xOffset + 5.0, y: p.y, width: width + 2, height: 14))
    label.text = text
    label.font = valueLabelFont
    label.textColor = valueLabelTextColor
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.backgroundColor = valueLabelBackgroundColor!

    self.addSubview(label)
    axisLabels.append(label)

}

for i in 0 ..< horizontalGridStep! + 1 {

    let text = labelForIndex(index: i)

    let p = CGPoint(x: margin! + CGFloat(i) * (axisWidth! / CGFloat(horizontalGridStep!)) * 1.0, y: axisHeight! + margin!)


    let rect = CGRect(x: margin!, y: p.y + 2, width: self.frame.size.width - margin! * 2 - 4.0, height: 14)
    let width = text.boundingRect(with: rect.size,
                                  options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                  attributes:[NSFontAttributeName : indexLabelFont!],
                                  context: nil).size.width

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: p.x - 5.0, y: p.y + 5.0, width: width + 2, height: 14))
    label.text = text
    label.font = indexLabelFont!
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.textColor = indexLabelTextColor!
    label.backgroundColor = indexLabelBackgroundColor!

    self.addSubview(label)
    axisLabels.append(label)

}
```